# WCF One ServiceHost for many WCF Libraries

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I host services from different wcf library at one place?

Supposed I have 2 WCF liberary dlls, look like this

.DLLA

```
 Public Class clientA : InterfaceA
```

.DLLB

```
 Public class clientB : InterfaceB
```

Both interfaces have service contract attribute and their own operation contract(s).
Both dlls I placed in a shared folder so I can load them dynamically and host them as services

Now I want to create a  “AutoHosting” console app as the middle layer but using only ONE SINGLE ServiceHost to host both of these services and assign with the same UriListen.

PS: Also I want the solution as flexible as it can. For example in the future I add DLLC I hope ServiceHost can pick up the DLLC service automatically without modifying “AutoHosting” part

please let me know the best approach if you have.

Comment: To do this one of two people are going to need to do some "extra work". Either the creator of the DLL needs to write it so the service can be run with no configuration settings in app.config (be it hard coded values or an alternate config file location) or the user of the DLL needs to modify his config file with the settings of the DLL's published endpoints. Which do you want to do, the solution for each is slightly different.

Comment: Also is it possible that DLLA and DLLB can both reference a single project that could define a master "plugin interface" that the DLLs would need to implement in a class that could return information like the names of the classes and interfaces they publish available inside the DLL.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your response. But it is fine because there are 50+ dlls need to add so if the extra work is necessary we will do it. The only solution I found from the web is to use partial class but I do not want to use it because every time I add some services or interfaces I need to recompile my dll

Comment: "****Also is it possible that DLLA and DLLB can both reference a single project that could define a master "plugin ........." Yes it is possible if no recompile needed when I remove/add new dll(s)

Comment: How do you want to handle configuration, config file per dll/hard coding or merging settings in to a master .config file at DLL install time?

Comment: **No, you cannot do this**. One `ServiceHost` hosts **exactly one** service implementation class. The only option would be to have one service implementation class that implements **multiple service contracts** (multiple interfaces).

Comment: marc & Scott, thanks to tell me it is not possible. But how can I build a fleixable middle layer for 50+ wcf libraries (in another word 50 + service implementation class in different dlls)  by using WCF??

Comment: @John by dropping the requirement of having a single `ServiceHost`. They all can be published under a single URL with different service names (`http://example.org/MyServices/ClientA`, `http://example.org/MyServices/ClientB`, ect.), and all reside within a single process, but you will need one service host per `class` that publishes endpoints no matter where that class came from.

Comment: Scott, yes I thought this approach but when clients dlls count more than 50+ I will have http://example.org/MyServices/Client01 ... http://example.org/MyServices/Client50 exposed. then you will fine the app.config is horrible if one client want to consume all of them

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in your question I think I finally understand your main issue.

> Scott, yes I thought this approach but when clients dlls count more than 50+ I will have example.org/MyServices/Client01 ... example.org/MyServices/Client50 exposed. then you will fine the app.config is horrible if one client want to consume all of them

If you want one master class that everything can talk through at once (and I am not saying this is a good idea, I would just go with the giant client app.config file) you will need to dynamically generate a class that will act as a service endpoint, implementing all of the interfaces defined and proxying the calls to the DLLs.

So in theory the master class would look something like

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMasterInterface : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
}

public class MasterClass : IMasterInterface
{
    public MasterClass()
    {
        aInstance = new DllA.clientA();
        bInstance = new DllB.clientB();
    }

    DllA.InterfaceA aInstance; //Use full namespaces to prevent conflicts.
    DllB.InterfaceB bInstance;

    public void DllA.InterfaceA.Foo() //Use explicit interfaces to prevent name conflicts
    {
        aInstance.Foo();
    }

    public bool DllB.InterfaceB.Foo()
    {
       return bInstance.Foo();
    }
}
```

Now for the requirement having to re-compile your program every time you add or remove a DLL, and the thing is, you still will do that *but not at development time*.

.NET provides classes that allow you to generate assemblies on the fly at runtime with [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). You would need to recreate the `MasterClass` and `IMasterInterface` classes every time the program started up (or at least whenever you detected a change in the DLLs). Just enumerate the DLLs and build up your single master class and interface.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I have no idea if this will break the contracts with clients when you rebuild with a new DLL added or removed. Also I have no idea how name conflicts will look at the client side. I still recommend you **do not** do this approach and just have a large `app.config` instead pointing at multiple endpoints. If you hand generate the `app.config` with a tool like [`SvcConfigEditor.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that comes with Visual Studio you can make it a lot smaller by re-using configuration sections between multiple similar services.